# Exception in downloading a file android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download a file with DownloadManager on android.

I get this exception: **Neither user 10073 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE.EXTERNAL.STORAGE.**

And here is my manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is where i try to download a file:

```
DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.examle.com/abc.jpg");

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setTitle("My File");
request.setDescription("Downloading");
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"abc.jpg");
downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Device has which Android version?

Comment: Did you also request permissions at runtime?

Comment: @blackapps Thanks, it did the job.